# angular github.io routing results in 404

Tags: angular, routes, github-pages

I'm working on a personal project that involves an angular UI. It works as desired locally, but when I deploy it to github.io, I can't get the routing to work. The routing is quite elementary, and despite hours of research, I've no idea what is wrong.

Here is the very limited routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'google', component: GoogleHandlerComponent}
];
```

Running locally, this route works as seen. The "1234" is a confirmation that the component is alive and working when the route is called.

[image]

However, when deployed to github.io, the resulting deployment (danhass.github.io) has a 404 (page not found) when the route is hit (https://danhass.github.io/google). However, the base href works fine (https://danhass.github.io).

I tried adding various base-hrefs to the ng build, with no success.

Comment: This definitely is a github thing. I've now published the test application to vercel directly from the same github repository (https:danhass.github.io.vercel.app) and there the routing works exactly as expected. Specfically, the "/google" routing on vercel renders exactly like it does when running on localhost:4200.

Comment: I "guess" the "solution" is: "Don't use github pages for you angular app. Vercel is also free, uses the same cicd, and works."

Comment: Unless, someone has a "real" solution, I'm going to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found for using Angular routes on github.io is to use the following configuration :

```
    ], providers: [
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    ],
```

But it will cost you not being able to use the anchors in your app.

For me, the best solution is the one you shared : using another system like [Vercel](https://vercel.com/)